# Visual Basic Form. How to let users save text file where they want

Tags: vb.net, winforms, savefiledialog

```
Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    Dim CurrentDir As String = Environment.CurrentDirectory
    Dim OutputFile2 As String = IO.Path.Combine(CurrentDir, "input.txt")
    IO.File.WriteAllLines(OutputFile2, Result1.Lines)
End Sub
```

Right now, I have coding that saves a text file in the current directory. However, I want to have a browse button for users so that they can pick where this text file is saved. How do I proceed this?

I was trying it by my self and I'm having a trouble with using save file dialog. If you can teach me how to use a save file dialog or anyway to write save browse button, I would very appreciate it!

Comment: What trouble were you having.  Be specific.

Comment: I found a save file dialog tool on the toolbox and tried to combine it with button but it did not work. I did not know how to start this basically.

Comment: "it did not work" -- be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object contains an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?c4s-lang=vb#code-snippet-2).

Comment: From the example, What does this mean by ' Code to write the stream goes here.'?
Should I write  IO.File.WriteAllLines(Stream, Result1.Lines)?

Comment: Instead of the code using `myStream`, use `IO.File.WriteAllLines(saveFileDialog1.FileName, Result1.Lines)`.

Comment: I tried that but it says it is being used by another process which does not make sense to me. I am not using this text file anyhow. It would only make a blank txt file on the location I indicated.

If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()
            If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                IO.File.WriteAllLines(saveFileDialog1.FileName, Result1.Lines)

Comment: As I said, you don't need any of the `myStream` code. The line `myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()` is causing your error message - the file is already open by the time the `WriteAllLines` method tries to use it. Yes, the message says "another" process, but all it means is that it tried to open the file and could not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial on how to implement SaveFileDialog using Toolbox in Visual Studio like you mentioned. The code sample is in C# but it can be easily converted to VB.

Link: [www.dotnetperls.com/savefiledialog](http://www.dotnetperls.com/savefiledialog)

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' When user clicks button, show the dialog.
    saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub saveFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs)
    ' Get file name.
    Dim name As String = saveFileDialog1.FileName
    ' Write to the file name selected.
    ' ... You can write the text from a TextBox instead of a string literal.
    File.WriteAllText(name, "test")
End Sub
```